# Placing a text on an image in Rails using ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip

I have implemented image upload with Paperclip and ImageMagick on a web app, and I'm trying to add a feature so users can add a short caption and it's placed ON the image itself. I tried figuring out a Paperclip processor, but that was too complicated, so stepped back and now trying to do it using ImageMagick. Here is my model:

```ruby
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
    validates :image, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true
    before_save :textOnImage

    def textOnImage
        require 'rubygems'
        require 'RMagick'
        include Magick
        require "open-uri"
        img = ImageList.new(image)
        txt = Draw.new
        img.annotate(txt, 0,0,0,0, "Testing"){
            txt.gravity = Magick::SouthGravity
            txt.pointsize = 25
            txt.stroke = ‘#000000’
            txt.fill = ‘#ffffff’
            txt.font_weight = Magick::BoldWeight
        }

        img.format = ‘jpeg’
        send_data img.to_blob, :stream => ‘false’, :filename => ‘test.jpg’, :type => ‘image/jpeg’, :disposition => ‘inline’

    end
end
```

I have tried all of the related answers on stackoverflow, but the closest I came to a solution is getting this error: undefined method `include' for #Photo:0x007fda7eaa87b8

I think it's because this is in the model and I can't use an Include tag in model? any suggestions?

Comment: what if you move your requires and includes to above `class Photo`, and start `textOnImage` with `img = ImageList.new(image)`?

Comment: Already tried that, in that case even the require does not work...